# How to update package.json from existing project?

Tags: npm, package.json

I followed some similar posts about this questions but for me it doesn't seem right. I did `npm init --yes` and now my `package.json` is containning a lot of dependencies, I feel like they aren't the project dependencies but the computer dependencies.

How can I update the `package.json` only with the actual project dependencies ?

[edit]

Or maybe it's my `node_modules` that contains too many useless things, how can I update it to fit the current project ?

Comment: Please update your question with code so people can have a clearer view of what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have one project with `node_modules` folder in it and you're running `npm init -y` command.

If this is the case, then yes, it'll include all the packages stored in `node_modules` as dependencies.

> contains too many useless thing

No, those are not useless but dependencies of your actual dependencies. You might try following to get actual idea.

---

Create a new folder, go inside the folder, create the `package.json` using `npm` and then install few dependencies.

```sh
# Create an example folder.
$ mkdir example1
# Go inside the created folder.
$ cd example1
# Create package.json file using npm.
$ npm init -y
# Install few packages.
$ npm i express morgan cors mongoose
```

Now, go ahead and delete both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files and then run the `npm init -y` command again. You'll see more than 50 packages as dependencies instead of 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice input and the explanations !